# How do you stop rewriterules stacking?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have `index.php` with two incoming query strings `$_GET['m']` for `movie` and `$_GET['u']` for `user`.

In my .htaccess file I have these 3 rewriterules:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?movie/(.*?)/?$ /index.php?m=$1 [L]`

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?profile/(.*?)/?$ /index.php?u=$1 [L]`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]`

I am sure there are some redundancies there, but that isn't my primary problem.

Say I am on `url.com/movie/TITLE/` after passing index.php?m=TITLE, I click a profile button, which should send me to a users profile by reloading index.php with ?u=USER. Instead of getting `url.com/movie/TITLE/` however, it stacks and I get the url `url.com/movie/profile/USER`.

How would this be avoided?

Comment: `RewriteBase /` ?

Comment: Neither `RewriteBase /` or adding `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` to RewriteCond (or both) appear to do anything. Problem persists.

Comment: You have to make all your links as relative to the domain root by preceding all links with a slash `/`. So you can't link to `profile/USER`, you have to link to `/profile/USER`. The browser thinks that `url.com/movie/TITLE` is loading a file named `TITLE` under a folder named `movie`. It has no knowledge of your rewrite rules, that is done on the server. So if you provide it a relative URL, it will load a page relative to where it thinks you are, under the `movie` directory. Same with external resources you include images, js, css...etc. This is an issue with your links, not the rewrite rules.

Comment: This solves the problem. Thank you! I don't know what the etiquette here is, in order to mark this question as closed. Would you repost this comment as a top-level reply?